# Missing column when setting up sqflite database table

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am currently developing an android application using the flutter framework. 
For setting up databases i am using the sqflite plugin.

Setting up the databases works as following:

```dart
  Future<Database> getDbModelDevice() async {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), dbNameDevice),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute("""
      CREATE TABLE $tableNameDevice (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        name TEXT NOT NULL, 
        ip TEXT NOT NULL
        )""");
    },
    version: 1,
    );
  }
```

This works as intended and creates the database with table. 
I am quite new to the topic so i dont know if you can somehow get to see the structure of the created table. I tried testing the new table by inserting a device in it:

```dart
Future<void> insertDevice(Device device) async {
  db.insert(
    tableNameDevice, 
    device.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
    'id': id,
    'name': name,
    'ip': ip,
  };
}
```

When calling the function ***insertDevice***, i get the following error message:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table deviceTable has no column named ip (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO deviceTable (id, name, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO deviceTable (id, name, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' args [0, testInsertion, 0.0.0.0]}
```

The other columns seem to work since the insertion works when commenting out the parameter ***ip*** in the ***toMap()*** function inserts the device without error.

What am i missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you uninstalled the application ?

Comment: The most obvious explanation for this would be that your table in fact does not contain an `ip` column.  You should drop the table, then recreate it and verify that all columns are really there.

Comment: @abdul until now i just tried flutter clean, but i will try uninstalling now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you know of an efficient way to somehow describe the table in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TimBiegeleisen's comment helped me solve the problem.
I was looking at my defined functions for dropping the tables and found out, that i was dropping the wrong tables.

Since i fixed that now it is working as intented.

Thanks for your answers!